# Activity class {com.example.lady/com.example.lady.MainActivity} does not exist

Tags: android, flutter

I create a simple app and it working fine on a physical phone.
But when I uninstalled it on phone and run it again in android studio it shows an error like this.

[image]

`AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]

Comment: Please post your activity class and manifest

Comment: Did you change your package name?

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel I never touch this file.I already added

Comment: @Andrej NO I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it buy uninstall from command to make sure uninstall successful
`adb uninstall <package_name>`